# Using Ogre OctreeSceneManager or Generic Scene Manager

Tags: ogre

Did somebody used OctreeSceneManager in Ogre? Is it faster for rendeing then Generic Scene Manager? I use OpenGL rendering system.

Answer (score 1):

(Better late than never ;-) )

Quoting the [Ogre Wiki](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/SceneManagersFAQ#Octree_Scene_Manager), an OSM (Octree Scene Manager)

> Uses an octree to split the scene and performs well for most scenes, except those which are reliant on heavy occlusion.

Now there's one big difference between a GSM (Generic Scene Manager) and an OSM:
The GSM relies on you, the developer, to build a scene node hierarchy while the OSM builds an octree of all scene nodes automatically in the background.
This means if you're going to add all your scene nodes to the root node, the GSM will be much slower<sup>1</sup>.
The usage of both remains the same, you're still free to order your nodes as you want.

When you do a lot of frustum culling or (ray) scene queries you may want to use the OSM, as it will perform better<sup>2</sup> (but just remember to not bunch all your scene nodes together under the root node).

Unless you have a scene which is reliant on heavy occlusion or you have to add all your scene nodes directly under the root node I'd prefer the OSM.

<sup>1</sup> - [GSM vs. OSM](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=70253#p458544)
<sup>2</sup> - [How to use OSM](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=73227#p472710)